# CSS Chrome transition bug

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm working on a site and I get a weird bug using transitions.

Website: http://nieuw.impress3d.nl/

I explain my actions below:

So if you visit the homepage the site is working fine and the hovers as well. (You can hover the big blocks in the middle of the page.)

If you then press the arrow to the right once in Chrome the background changes to the background color of the article and the image disappear behind it!

If I turn off overflow: hidden, it works fine, but then the whole idea of the transition would be gone.

Is this a known bug? And are there any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the css responsible for hover transiotions AND the code responsible for slider movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `translateZ(0)` :

```
.project figure img,
.service figure img,
.owl-item figure img,
.service-item figure img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
}
```